# Whan can maven-metadata.xml tell about the time of an upload in Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-metadata

In artifactory we have some local repo's. 
One of the repo's contains a lot of subfolders. 
Each subfolder contains a `maven-metadata.xml` and a lot of other folders and subfolders.

is the `maven-metadata.xml` updated very time with the same date as the date of the last updated file in that folder?

I'm searching for an easy way to check when an artifact was last uploaded/updated without checking every file in every subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date inside `maven-metadata.xml` files should be to update if you upload every time that you:

- Upload a new artifact version of an existing artifact
- Upload a new artifact.

So you can use this date as reference.

Comment: do you maybe know when the .index is updated? It seems to be updated very recently but there was not a new upload.